# How to specify Options for a custom Import converter?

Tags: import, options, customization

Mathematica includes [`RegisterImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) to setup custom functions which read and translate file data for [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html), effectively allowing it to be extended for any format. One can get a list of information that `Import` can return for a file type like so:

```
Import["ExampleData/lena.tif", {"TIFF", "Elements"}]
(* {Animation,Author,BitDepth,CameraTopOrientation,<<22>>,Thumbnail,ThumbnailList,TileSize} *)
```

This listing behavior is set up automatically by `RegisterImport` for correctly specified elements.

Options for functions registered to `Import` can be set up in the standard way and passed through the options given to the `Import` command:

```
Import["ExampleData/lena.tif", {"TIFF", "Image"}, ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

There's a similar syntax to see available options specific to the specified file format:

```
Import["ExampleData/lena.tif", {"TIFF", "Options"}]
(* {"BitDepth" -> 8, "ColorSpace" -> RGBColor, "Comments" -> None, "ImageSize" -> {150, 116}} *)
```

**What needs to be done so that options for user-specified functions registered to `Import` appear in this listing?**

So far I haven't been able to find any help docs or discussion on this topic.

Comment: Interesting question.  It appears that the element `"Options"` is itself reserved, i.e. returning element rules like ``{"dummy" -> 1, "Options" -> Options[foo`import]}`` does not work, whereas ``{"dummy" -> 1, "Opts" -> Options[foo`import]}`` works for `"Opts"`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, the call to `RegisterImport` seems to set up "Rules", "Elements", and "Options" on it own based on input. I think "Rules" comes from the default function (specified in the call to `RegisterImport`), but I don't see where "Options" come in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options isn't used very often, and doesn't do exactly what it sounds like. You are correct the Import framework has a few elements that it knows how to do for every format: All, "Rules", "Options", "Elements". Rules is a list of rules with elementName -> data for every element. All is a list of the data without the element name. "Options" allows you to specify at registration a list of elements that would be returned if you ask for "Options", importing that subset of elements.

```
In[33]:= ImportExport`RegisterImport["fmt", 
    {"Data" -> ("Data" -> 1 &), 
    "Foo" -> ("Foo" -> 2 &), 
    Bar" -> ("Bar" -> 3 &)
    }, 
    "DefaultElement" -> "Data", 
    "Options" -> {"Data", "Bar"}]

In[34]:= ImportString["", "fmt"]

Out[34]= 1

In[35]:= ImportString["", {"fmt", "Foo"}]

Out[35]= 2

In[36]:= ImportString["", {"fmt", "Options"}]

Out[36]= {"Bar" -> 3, "Data" -> 1}
```

"Options" does not give a list of options supported by the format. I'm not sure why one would want to do this, but that's how it works. There is currently no way to get a list of options that a format accepts, maybe in future versions. As far as creating options that work with a custom format, it is done like this:

```
ImportExport`RegisterImport["fmt", myFunc, "DefaultElement" -> "Data"]
Options[myFunc] = {"opt" -> "val", ..}
```

Now you could call:

```
Import[.., "fmt", "opt" -> "newval"]
```